# Цикл на JavaScript

Tags: jquery, массивы, javascript

Здравствуйте. Есть такой вопрос. У меня есть таблица, а в ней много `INPUT`'ов. Можно ли как-нибудь `JavaScript`'ом собрать все эти значения в массив?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
var mass = new Array();
$("table input").each(function(){
    mass.push($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает. Можно еще `mass[i]=$(this).val(); i++;`

Comment: Вообще в этом случае лучше использовать map:

    var mass = $("table input").map(function(){
        return $(this).val();
    });